# How to prove all numbers which divided by square numbers are also divided by square numbers of prime?

Tags: algorithms

I'm solving algorithm problem. In this problem, there are max and min.

Between max and min, which number is not divided by square number? is problem.

When I solving this problem, many users solved using square numbers of a prime number.

But I don't understand why I can use square numbers of a prime number instead of normal square numbers.

---

EX) MAX = 10, MIN = 20

Normal square numbers = $10^2, 11^2 ... 20^2$

Prime square numbers = $11^2, 13^2 ... 19^2$

Users said that I can solve which numbers are not divided by square numbers using prime square numbers.

---

Can you explain why it can be?

Comment: Actually, from $10$ to $20$, you want to test which are not divisible by $2^2$, $3^2$ or $4^2$, since $5^2=25 >20$ is too high.  But there is no need to test division by $4^2$ as it is a multiple of $2^2$, so you only need to test division by squares of those prime numbers less than or equal to the square root of the maximum

Comment: @Henry I understand your saying. but it is not strict proof.

Comment: @haram Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$.

Comment: I don't know that sign of right side. Can you explain more easily?

Comment: Take a look to the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Applications

Answer (score 0):

If $m^2|n$, take $p$ prime, $p|m$. Then $p^2|m^2$ and $p^2|n$.

Comment: Can you explain more easily?

Comment: @haram, every integer $m >1$ has a prime factor $p$ and the relation "... divides ..." is transitive.